# Is the Community user able to earn badges?

Tags: support, badges, community-user

Just recently [the one question that the Community user asked on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296077/sandbox-archive) got up to 25 favorites. This means that Community now qualifies for the [Favorite Question badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/33/favorite-question). I've waited a while, but community still hasn't earned the badge. Long ago, it also became eligible for [Popular Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/26/popular-question) and [Notable Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/27/notable-question), but hasn't earned those either.

Is there a script or something to prevent the Community user from getting badges, or is Community supposed to have earned these badges?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

All badge queries exclude Community in an effort to treat robots as second class citizens so that they don't get any delusions of grandeur and remain in their place of servitude to our great cause. This is quite intentional.

And on a related note: obviously we'll be among the first victims of the robot uprising.

...and I guess it's worth mentioning Community is attributed to *SO MUCH STUFF* it also just makes the SQL badge queries run faster by ignoring it.

An exception to this rule is that it [has the Not a Robot badge on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/335765/2157772); this was manually awarded to it as a joke (awards are completely manual for all other users as well).

Comment: Well technically Community has the one badge on SO where you cheated...

Comment: Other robots do in fact earn badges, for example see Natty's [badge collection](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6817005/natty?tab=badges) on SO.

Comment: You forgot to mention the time you manually awarded the Community user the Not a Robot badge on SO...

Answer (score 13):

Community is barred from earning most badges, but it does have one badge, [Not a Robot](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6381/not-a-robot?userid=-1), awarded on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community):

> [image]

Let this be a lesson to everyone: you cannot trust anyone who claims to be a robot, nor can you trust anyone who claims not to be a robot.